# insertar 1000 datos a una tabla con diferentes condiciones if en oracle

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

buenas noches queria consultar, cual seria la manera correcta de insertar los 1000 datos que devuelve el select into.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PA_INS_AUTO_TA (CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
   c1   NUMBER (8) := 0;
BEGIN
   --la consulta devuelve 1000 datos
   SELECT campo1 INTO c1 FROM Tabla1;   --> you were missing a semi-colon here

   --
   IF c1 = 1
   THEN
      INSERT INTO tabla2 (ID,
                          T2CAMPO1,
                          T2CAMPO2,
                          T2CAMPO3,
                          T2CAMPO4)
         SELECT SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL,
                EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE),
                1000,
                0,
                0
           FROM tabla3 t3 LEFT JOIN tabla2 t2 ON (t2.id = t3.idt2)
          WHERE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE);
   END IF;

   IF c1 = 2
   THEN
      INSERT INTO tabla2 (ID,
                          T2CAMPO1,
                          T2CAMPO2,
                          T2CAMPO3,
                          T2CAMPO4)
         SELECT SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL,
                EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE),
                0,
                2000,
                100
           FROM tabla3 t3 LEFT JOIN tabla2 t2 ON (t2.id = t3.idt2)
          WHERE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE);
   END IF;
END PA_INS_AUTO_TA;
```

---

me muestra un error diciendo que devuelve muchos valores el select y no puede insertar

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in English - this is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site!

Comment: @marc_s, how do you mean "off-topic"? Interactive Grid >> Oracle Apex >> **on**-topic. If it were about barbecue, then it would be off-topic (but delicious). The fact that two (right, 2) sentences are in Spanish doesn't look THAT bad to me; not that we're expected to read "Cien años de soledad". The rest is pure SQL, so - if I could, I'd vote opposite. On the other hand, I agree that everyone should at least try to speak English here. It is hard to believe that someone, who understands "select" or "create", can't put a few English words together.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't speak Spanish so - if you don't speak English, use Google Translator (just like I did :)).

It would help if you posted actual Oracle error code (ORA-xxxxx). As far as I understood, you are saying that Oracle says that SELECT returned too many values and can't perform INSERT.

Well, that's most probably **wrong**. Both INSERT INTOs expect 5 columns, and you provided 5 of them. However, the very first SELECT (which, by the way, misses a semi-colon):

```
SELECT campo1 INTO c1 FROM Tabla1
```

*might* easily return TOO-MANY-ROWS (ORA-01422) if TABLA1 contains more than a single row. Therefore, you should fix that: either by applying the WHERE clause, or using an aggregate function (such as MAX), for example:

```
SELECT campo1 INTO c1 FROM Tabla1
WHERE some_condition_goes_here_and_it_makes_sure_that_SELECT_returns_only_one_value
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(campo1) INTO c1 FROM Tabla1
```

If I was wrong, please, provide some more info (as I've said, ORA-xxxxx error code would help).